# In which array can we find elements in Julia?

Tags: arrays, julia, membership

Imagine we have the following array of 3 arrays, covering the range 1 to 150:

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10  ...  41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]`

`[51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60  ...  92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 107]`

`[71, 73, 84, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 108  ...  141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150]`

I want to build an array that stores in which array we find the values 1 to 150. The result must be then:

`[1 1 1 ... 1 2 2 2 ... 2 3 2 3 2 ... 3 3 3 ... 3]`,

where each element corresponds to 1, 2, 3, ... ,150. The obtained array gives then the array-membership of the elements 1 to 150. The code must be applied for any number of arrays (so not only 3 arrays).

Comment: I've seen several questions like this recently. Please be aware that it is considered good form on Stack Overflow to give evidence that you have attempted to answer the question yourself, and failed. The following [blog post](https://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) gives an excellent explanation as to why. Even just posting some non-working attempt to solve the problem in your question is much more likely to motivate good answers.

Comment: I tried several commands such as  find ,  findin or indexin which all failed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [array comprehension](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/arrays/#Comprehensions-1). Here is an example with three vectors containing the range `1:10`:

```
A = [1, 3, 4, 5, 7]
B = [2, 8, 9]
C = [6, 10]
```

Now we can write a comprehension using `in` with a fallback error to guard :

```
julia> [x in A ? 1 : x in B ? 2 : 3 for x in 1:10]
10-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 ⋮
 3
```

Perhaps also include a fallback error, in case the input is wrong

```
julia> [x in A ? 1 : x in B ? 2 : x in C ? 3 : error("not found") for x in 1:10]
10-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 ⋮
 3
```

Comment: Ok. I will try to expand it for any number of arrays. Not only 3, because the original idea is to apply it to an array of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Trade memory for search in this case:

- Make an `array` to record which `array` each value is in.

```
# example arrays
N=100; A=rand(1:N,30);
B = rand(1:N,40);
C = rand(1:N,35);
# record array containing each value: 
A=1,B=2,C=3; 
not found=0;
arrayin = zeros(Int32, max(maximum(A),maximum(B),maximum(C))); 
arrayin[A] .= 1; 
arrayin[B] .= 2; 
arrayin[C] .=3;
```